# How come two false OR (||) to true in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below is a small code snippet. Can't really understand what mistake I am making, but two false when ORed (||) is resulting into true. Can someone help me please?
Here is the code:

```
let result = {isVerified: 'verified'}
console.log(result.isVerified, !result.isVerified, result.isVerified !== 'verified', ((!result.isVerified) || (result.isverified !== 'verified')));
```

I am using node version v14.16.1

Answer (score 1):

try using this code
You have writen **isVerified as isverified**

```
let result = { isVerified: "verified" };
console.log(
  result.isVerified,
  !result.isVerified,
  result.isVerified !== "verified",
  !result.isVerified || result.isVerified !== "verified"
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Please do not ANSWER typo-type questions